# Android webview with PDF load

Tags: android, pdf, webview

I am loading a page inside the webview

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("https://www.xxxxxxxxx/howtoguide.aspx");
```

then inside the webview I have several function to click event below

```
            @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            if (url.contains("concierge@xxxx.com.sg")) {
                final Intent eIntent = new Intent(
                        android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                eIntent.setType("plain/text");
                eIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                        new String[]{"xxxxxx"});
                eIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                        "");
                eIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                        "Text to be send");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(eIntent,
                        "Send mail..."));

            } else if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                view.reload();

            } else if (url.contains(".pdf")) {
            //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            //intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "application/pdf");
            //try{
            //view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            //} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            //user does not have a pdf viewer installed
            //}
            // view.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" + url);
               view.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + url);               
            } else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }
            return true;
        }
```

in this webview there is a click event for PDF. So if I click this the PDF not loading

Comment: are you sure that the link to PDF file contains the `.pdf` in it? Also you can set the breakpoint in your `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method, and check what is wrong by yourself using debug.

Comment: yeah, It has the .pdf. I have added this PDF string as statically after that also not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
view.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + url);
```

This method call working for me, when I called to load inside the webview. So this webview layout height should be match_parent.

Link click open the browser then simply pass the URL like below code.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
```

This is solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below example code for your requirement

```
private void init()
{
    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

    MyWebViewClient webViewClient = new MyWebViewClient(this, webview);
    webViewClient.loadUrl(YOUR_URL);
}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
{
    private static final String TAG = "MyWebViewClient";
    private static final String PDF_EXTENSION = ".pdf";
    private static final String PDF_VIEWER_URL = "https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=";

    private Context mContext;
    private WebView mWebView;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private boolean isLoadingPdfUrl;

    public MyWebViewClient(Context context, WebView webView)
    {
        mContext = context;
        mWebView = webView;
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(this);
    }

    public void loadUrl(String url)
    {
        mWebView.stopLoading();

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(url))
        {
            isLoadingPdfUrl = isPdfUrl(url);
            if (isLoadingPdfUrl)
            {
                mWebView.clearHistory();
            }

            showProgressDialog();
        }

        mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url)
    {
        return shouldOverrideUrlLoading(url);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView webView, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
    {
        handleError(errorCode, description.toString(), failingUrl);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, WebResourceRequest request)
    {
        final Uri uri = request.getUrl();
        return shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webView, uri.toString());
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(final WebView webView, final WebResourceRequest request, final WebResourceError error)
    {
        final Uri uri = request.getUrl();
        handleError(error.getErrorCode(), error.getDescription().toString(), uri.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, final String url)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading. URL : " + url);
        dismissProgressDialog();
    }

    private boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final String url)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "shouldOverrideUrlLoading() URL : " + url);

        if (url.contains("concierge@xxxx.com.sg"))
        {
            Intent eIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            eIntent.setType("plain/text");
            eIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"xxxxxx"});
            eIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
            eIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text to be send");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(eIntent, "Send mail..."));
            return true;
        }
        else if (url.startsWith("tel:"))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        else if (!isLoadingPdfUrl && isPdfUrl(url))
        {
            mWebView.stopLoading();

            final String pdfUrl = PDF_VIEWER_URL + url;

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    loadUrl(pdfUrl);
                }
            }, 300);

            return true;
        }

        return false; // Load url in the webView itself
    }

    private void handleError(final int errorCode, final String description, final String failingUrl)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error : " + errorCode + ", " + description + " URL : " + failingUrl);
    }

    private void showProgressDialog()
    {
        dismissProgressDialog();
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "", "Loading...");
    }

    private void dismissProgressDialog()
    {
        if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing())
        {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            mProgressDialog = null;
        }
    }

    private boolean isPdfUrl(String url)
    {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(url))
        {
            url = url.trim();
            int lastIndex = url.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(PDF_EXTENSION);
            if (lastIndex != -1)
            {
                return url.substring(lastIndex).equalsIgnoreCase(PDF_EXTENSION);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Checkout the example code for handling redirect urls and open PDF without download, in webview. https://gist.github.com/ashishdas09/014a408f9f37504eb2608d98abf49500

Comment: new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        webView.loadUrl(http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + url);
                    }
                }, 300);

even if I add that link directly also not working

Comment: If its possible can you share the url?

Comment: Inside the 
 @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view, final String url) {
I have added this this code with sample PDF then the app downloading the PDF instead of loading 
 String pdf = "http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";
view.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);

Comment: When I call direct URL like this then it's working fine 
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl(pdf );
but not inside the @Override public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading method for click event.

Comment: Its working fine for me please checkout the example code for handling redirect urls and open PDF without download, in webview.
https://gist.github.com/ashishdas09/014a408f9f37504eb2608d98abf49500

Comment: Where can I find these methods ?
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, WebResourceRequest request)
WebResourceRequest 

If it works for this then it's should work for my code as well right ??

Comment: shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
This method was deprecated in API level 24. Use shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView, WebResourceRequest) instead.

Comment: If you see my code i have added annotation for target api on method so it will work for all API level.

Comment: @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, WebResourceRequest request)
        {
            final Uri uri = request.getUrl();
            return shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webView, uri.toString());
        }

In this line even If add this also showing the msg 
Method does not override method from its superclass

Comment: This is the PDF URL http://feast2.surfgold.net/AppPages/feast_howtoguide_V5.pdf

If I click the URL directly like this  webView.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=http://feast2.surfgold.net/AppPages/feast_howtoguide_V5.pdf");

Then it's loading in the browser but showing No preview available message... 
Can you please suggest me..

Comment: You can also use the this url (https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=) instead of (http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=).

Answer (score 0):

That the use of these methods need to log in to Google.

Other way use [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/)

You must save pdf file into sdcard and load in webview.

Add the pdfjs files to your Assets directory

```
 else if (url.contains(".pdf"))
        {
           File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.pdf");

   view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "#zoom=page-width"); 
        }
```

[Full sample project](https://github.com/loosemoose/androidpdf)

Comment: Initially I have load the URL into the webview then inside that that webview contains the PDF URL. So If I click that Link need to open the PDF. I don't understand anything from your answer.

Comment: Can you please explain me the way ??

Comment: Add sample project link

Comment: the pdfjs page is rendered nicely inside the webview... but the pdf file is not... any clues?